# Excel ODBC and 64 bit server

Tags: excel, 64-bit, odbc, windows-server-2008, 32-bit

using ASP.NET I need to update an excel template.

Our server is running Windows 2008 in 64 bit mode.

I am using the following code to access the excel file:

```
    ...
    string connection = 
@"Provider=MSDASQL;Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};DBQ=" + path + ";";
    ...
```

IF the application pool is set to Enable 32 bit applications the code works as expected; however the oracle driver I am using fails as it is only 64 bit.

If Enable 32-bit applications is set to false the excel code fails with the error:

> Data source name not found and no
>   default driver specified

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

The Microsoft Office team has just **released** a **[64-bit driver](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en)**

Comment: FYI, that driver is only for Office 2010 and up

Comment: This only  works if you set the application pool to Enable 32-bit applications to true for a Classic ASP application however.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728007/microsoft-access-database-engine-2010-redistributable-64-bit-only-works-if-enabl

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft release a 64bit OLEDB FOR ODBC in 2008/04/04
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=000364db-5e8b-44a8-b9be-ca44d18b059b&DisplayLang=en

Now you should able to run everything 64bit, can u try it and let us know the result and personally I think Microsoft should release a 64bit Jet Oledb 4.0, if the development team has no time to do it then just put it in codeplex.com and let other programmers do it.

Answer (score 2):

There is also **2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components**
[Link](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C06B8369-60DD-4B64-A44B-84B371EDE16D&displaylang=en#Overview) which has allowed us to open Excel 2007 (XLS) from a 64bit environment.

> This download will install a set of components that can be used by non-Microsoft Office applications to read data from Microsoft Office 2010 Beta files

Our connection string

```
@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " + filePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\""
```

Comment: If you have a 32bit version of Office installed, it will give you an error message when you try to install it.  But if you execute it with the `/passive` flag from the command line, it'll install side by side just fine.

Comment: Use of the /passive flag helped me out so much, thanks!!! I was about to reinstall all of Office!

Answer (score 0):

There are no office drivers for 64bit released.

The (currently) last post at this link:
[MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/213b90cb-5aea-41be-b935-fa995b6322ca/) details a cumbersome and ugly workaround. You could also replace the Windows Service with a COM exposed assembly, if you wish. Still ugly though. :)

Comment: There seems to be a solution to this problem now through 2010 Office System Driver Beta: Data Connectivity Components

Answer (score -1):

Install the 32-bit Oracle driver and enable 32 bit applications?

Comment: It's perhaps better to stick to what microsoft provides for 64 bit environments.

Comment: Agreed. MS provided drivers in 2010.